# Deleting Contents of a folder selevtively with python

Tags: python, shutil

I would periodically like to delete the contents of a Windows directory which includes files and sub directories that contain more files.  However I do not there is one specific file that I do not want to remove (it is the same file every time). I am using `shutil.rmtree` to delete the contents of a folder but I am deleting the file I wish to keep also. How would I make an exception preventing the removal of the file I would like to keep and is `shutil` the best method for this?

Comment: How about a work-around; copy the file to a secure location, wipe the directory, restore the file from the secure location. Step 2 should be conditional on the success of step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of pathnames in a directory, use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

Say you want to only find `.gif` files and delete those:

```
import glob
gif_list = glob.glob('your/path/name/'+'*.gif')
```

For your path, this finds all the files that end in `.gif`. You can delete them, copy them, do whatever you want.

Or, use list comprehension:

```
import glob
#just get a list of all the files/folders in your path:
path_list = glob.glob('your/path/name/'+'*')
gif_list = [x for x in file_list if x[-4:] == '.gif']
```

Glob  will also find all folders, of course. You can filter out which files and/or folders you want to keep, and delete the rest with `rmtree`. For example, say you wanted to keep the file called `keep.me`:

```
import glob 
path_list = glob.glob('your/path/name/'+'*')
del_list = [x for x in path_list if x != 'your/path/name/'+'keep.me']
```

Something like this should work.
Try it out!

Comment: this works but how to I use `rmtree` on a list instead of a directory?

Comment: As `rmtree` takes a path as an argument, you iterate over the files/directories in your list and delete them one by one.

Comment: If you only want to call `rmtree` once you can load your `keep.me` file before deleting, then copy it back after deleting. This method probably will not scale as well though.

Answer (score 0):

`rmtree` does not appear to have any kind of filtering mechanism that you could use; further, since part of its functionality is to remove the directory itself, and not just its contents, it wouldn't make sense to.

If you could do something to the file so that `rmtree`'s attempt to delete it fails, you can have `rmtree` ignore such errors, thus leaving your file but deleting the others.  If you cannot, you could resort to `os.walk` to loop over the contents of your directory, and thus decide which items to remove for yourself.

Comment: what do you mean "do something". I can not use @david182 suggestion because network permission would require me to contact IT every time I need to edit the file.

Comment: That's why there is more than 1 sentence in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

is it just one file or a ton of files?
Becouse if its just this one file you could just right click - properties - sercurity and check 'deny' everywhere

http://www.technorms.com/27407/prevent-files-from-being-deleted-windows